# Drag and drop feature in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a question that is there any feature available in JFreeChart to drag and drop the points within Chart.
I want to move the chart point and generate the straight line between new points.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a `JFreeChart` is not a `JComponent`; you can transfer the chart as a whole, but not individual component entities. Alternatively, you can combine the two approaches shown below "to move the chart point and generate the straight line between new points."

1. Move a chart point using an adjacent component such `Slider`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207445/230513).

   [image: slider image]
2. Connect the points in an XY line chart, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15207445/230513), or plot the corresponding regression line, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37716411/230513).

   [image: regression image]